# iOS Designated Initializers : Using NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, initialization, xcode6

We have this new macro being introduced in XCode 6 : NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER

I searched on the net, but couldn't really find any good documentation as to how to use this.

Syntactically, we can use it like :

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
```

But what are the possible advantages of marking an initializer with this macro, and also what are the things we should be looking at when using this ?

I am mainly interested in the use cases of this macro. Any links / documentation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The use of `NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER` is nicely explained in http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/08/19/xcode-6-objective-c-modernization.html:

> The designated initializer guarantees the object is fully initialised
>   by sending an initialization message to the superclass. The
>   implementation detail becomes important to a user of the class when
>   they subclass it. The rules for designated initializers in detail:
>
> - A designated initializer must call (via super) a designated
>     initializer of the superclass. Where NSObject is the superclass this
>     is just [super init].
> - Any convenience initializer must call another
>     initializer in the class - which eventually leads to a designated
>     initializer.
> - A class with designated initializers must implement all
>     of the designated initializers of the superclass.

As an example, if your interface is

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *name;
-(instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
-(instancetype)init;
@end
```

then the compiler checks if the (convenience) initializer `init` calls
the (designated) initializer `initWithName:`, so this would cause a warning:

```
-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}
```

and this would be OK:

```
-(instancetype)init
{
    self = [self initWithName:@""];
    return self;
}
```

In *Swift* the rules about designated and convenience initializers are even more strict,
and if you mix Objective-C and Swift code, marking the designated Objective-C initializers helps the compiler to enforce the rules.

For example, this Swift subclass would cause an compiler error:

```
class SwClass: MyClass {
    var foo : String
    init(foo : String) {
        self.foo = foo
        super.init()
    }
}
```

and this would be OK:

```
class SwClass: MyClass {
    var foo : String
    init(foo : String) {
        self.foo = foo
        super.init(name: "")
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not very well thought through concept in Objective-C because `initWithName:@""` does not always make sense when subclassing. Instead normally overridden designated initializer from superclass should throw exception saying to use designated initializer from subclass.

Comment: To add to Martin's answer, you may want to completely suppress the user from calling the default initialisers, in which case you can use the following:   
      
- (instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;

Answer (score 19):

My most common way to do this:

```
@interface Person : NSObject

- (nullable instancetype)initWithName:(nonnull NSString *)name NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (nullable instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;

@property (nonatomic, nonnull) NSString *name;

@end
```

And implementation

```
@implementation Person

- (instancetype)initWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.name = name;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

In this case you should not override `NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER` of your superclass method (`NSObject`'s `init:` in this case) - we used `NS_UNAVAILABLE` to mark this method as unneeded. Or you can override it to call your designated initializer with default parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Designated initializers define how we structure our initializers when subclassing; they are the “canonical initializer” for your class. It guaranteed to be reliable regardless of which designated initializer in the superclass chain you call, and will always go from furthest ancestor to furthest descendant.

A designated initializer does not define what initializer you should use when creating an object. It's very explained in https://blog.twitter.com/2014/how-to-objective-c-initializer-patterns.