# How to initialize a subclass when the init method of the superclass is NS_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing

I'm attempting to write a test for an objective-c class. The class I'm trying to test is `MyClass` and it looks like this:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
- (void)dispatchEvent:(IMAAdEvent *)event;
@end
```

In order to test this `dispatchEvent` method, I need to pass in an instance of `IMAAdEvent`. The `IMAAdEvent` class comes from Google's library `GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK`.

Unfortunately, I can't call `init` on this class because the init method is marked as `NS_UNAVAILABLE`. In XCode I get an error that reflects this:

> 'init' in unavailable

Ideally, I would like to make my own mock subclass of `IMAAdEvent` like this. Is there some way I can initialize my subclass without calling the unavailable init method on the superclass?:

```
@interface MockImaAdEvent : IMAAdEvent
@end

@implementation MockImaAdEvent
- (id)init {
  // is there something I can do here so that I return an instances
  // of the subclass without calling [super init]?
}
@end
```

Comment: You can't create an instance of Obj-C SubClass without calling super class initialiser.

Comment: Rather than trying to call init you can assume some default values for it's designated  initialiser and call it inside SubClass init method.

Comment: @ShreeramBhat thanks for your suggestion! If possible do you mind showing me with an example? Right now, when I call `[super init]` the compiler complains and says `'init' is unavailable`, when I look more into this I can see the init method is protected with `NS_UNAVAILABLE`

Comment: If you look at the class interface you can see init methods with NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER  macro. Use that init methods for your purpose.

Comment: For more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185239/ios-designated-initializers-using-ns-designated-initializer

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense! But the interface is here, I don't see the NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER macro: https://github.com/kaltura/player-sdk-demo-ios/blob/master/ovp/IMADemo/GoogleInteractiveMediaAds.framework/Versions/A/Headers/IMAAdEvent.h

Comment: Ok. That class is not allowing outsiders to initialise. Only some special class inside the library is the only one that can initialise it. You can also notice that all the properties are readOnly. So the purpose of that class is just give  info. to users.

Comment: Right, so that makes it difficult to create for my unit tests :/ thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

As of Xcode 12.5, Swift is no longer able to use the previous solution. The compiler has started returning errors for `init() is unavailable` on lines of code where new `init` functions have been added. The Xcode 12.5 Release Notes indicate the following:

> Clang now infers the availability of +new from availability annotations on -init methods. Since +new calls [[Foo alloc] init], +new isn’t available unless +init is available.

Despite this release note, there is still a valid workaround. By writing the mock class in Objective-C and using a bridging-header to bring it into Swift, the mock class can still call `super.new` to get a new instance of the parent class (and then customize the subclass from there).

Here is an example:

```
@interface MockInAppMessagingCampaignInfo ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *campaignNameValue;

@end

@implementation MockInAppMessagingCampaignInfo

+ (id)newWithCampaignName:(NSString *)campaignName {
    MockInAppMessagingCampaignInfo *newObject = super.new;
    newObject.campaignNameValue = campaignName;
    return newObject;
}

- (NSString *)campaignName {
    self.campaignNameWasCalled = YES;
    return self.campaignNameValue ?: @"";
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative solution for Xcode 12.5 that doesn't require Objective-C bridging-header is to create a custom static initialiser that uses the objc runtime to invoke new.

I have used that for fakes that subclass objects with unavailable initialisers and works great.

Example:

```
static func customInit() -> SomeObjectFake {
    let instance = SomeObjectFake.perform(NSSelectorFromString("new")).takeRetainedValue() as! SomeObjectFake
    ...
    return instance
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I use a method that's not called `init` then this seems to work. It still seems really weird to not call `[super init]` in this function, but it's working and returning a new instance of the `MockImaAdEvent` class

```
@interface MockImaAdEvent : IMAAdEvent {
    enum IMAAdEventType type;
}
    @property (nonatomic) enum IMAAdEventType type;
@end

@implementation MockImaAdEvent

@synthesize type;

- (id)initWithType:(NSInteger)_type {
    type = _type;
    return self;
}
@end

// in my test I can initialize like this:
MockImaAdEvent *adEvent = [[MockImaAdEvent alloc] initWithType:kIMAAdEvent_LOADED];
```

Comment: (At least for Swift), this is no longer working as of Xcode 12.5. It has started throwing build errors for "init() is unavailable" on the lines of code where new "init" functions had been added

Comment: @HenryGlendening did you find any workaround for xcode 12.5? I just updated and facing the same

Comment: @JavierVieira Unfortunately no, not yet. I'm switching back to Xcode 12.4 in the interim

Comment: @HenryGlendening thanks, I did the same... seems that might not be possible at all. I will let you know if I find some workaround

Comment: @JavierVieira I've got mocks working again in Swift. You'll need to write the mocks in Obj-C though and bridge them over. See my answer below for more info

Comment: @HenryGlendening cool, I will try it out, thanks a lot for sharing